# How to prove that the intersection of ideals is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Given $R$ is a ring, $X\subseteq H_i$ and $H_i$ is an ideal of $G$ for each $i=1,2,...,n$.

 Prove that $H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$ is an ideal of $G$ and contains $X$.

 
 That is a question I get from random source. I myself am not sure whether the question is right or not since $G$ is not defined yet, so I just assume that $G$ is the ring $R$ .

 
 A literature states that:

 Given non-empty set $S$, $S \subseteq R$, $S$ is an ideal if 

 $\forall s_1,s_2 \in S$, $s_1-s_2 \in S$, and

 $(\forall r \in R) (\forall s \in S)$ $rs,sr \in S$.

 
 Here is my try:

 For $i=1,2,...,n$, $H_i$ is an ideal of $R$ which means that $H_i\subseteq R$ and thus also  $H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n \subseteq R$

 To prove that  $H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$ is an ideal of $R$, It should be shown that 

 $\forall a,b \in H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$, $a-b \in H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$, and

 $(\forall r \in R) (\forall a \in H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n)$ $ra,ar \in H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$. 

 What confused me is that I don't know what guarantee $a-b,ra,ar \in H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$, and $X$ is contained in $G$.

Can anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: By G do you mean R, throughout?

Comment: This is ultimately just an exercise in definitions.

Comment: @awllower, I have edited my question and put my try on it.

Comment: @rschwieb, The question doesn't define $G$, so yeah, I just assume that $G$ is the ring $R$.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I know, but I don't know what guarantee $a-b,ra,ar \in H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$ and thus I can not say they fit the definition.

Comment: @MonicaSendiAfa Do you know what it means for the statement $a\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n H_i$ to hold? More specifically, do you know what the intersection of the sets is?

Comment: @awllower, Not really. For your specific question, could it be $X$ itself? Honestly, I don't really understand what the intersection of the sets is. Could you kindly explain it?

Comment: Have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)).

Comment: @awllower, thank you for the link. I read in "Arbitrary intersections" part, for this case, $x \in ∩ H_i ⇔ \forall X \in H_i, x \in X$, but can I conclude that the intersection of the sets $H_i$ is $X$?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the definitions: it ought to be $x \in ∩ H_i \iff \forall i, x \in H_i.$ I don't even know what this mysterious $X$ is! Some murderer? :P

Comment: @awllower, Ah yeah, I understand the definition now. Haha, well, what I mean by $X$ is the subset of $H_i$ I mention in the begining of my question. awllower, what guarantees that the second condition of intersections of $H_i$ be an ideal?

Answer (score 4):

Put $S=H_1\cap\cdots\cap H_n$.

To see that $S$ is an ideal, just verify that for any $a\in S$ and $r\in R$, we have (i) $ra\in S$ because $\forall i:a\in H_i$ by definition of $S$ and $\forall i:ra\in H_i$ by definition of ideal, hence $ra\in S$; we also have that (ii) $a,b\in S\Rightarrow a+b\in S$, since certainly $\forall i:a,b\in H_i$ by definition of $S$ and $\forall i:a+b\in H_i$ by definition of ideal, hence $a+b\in S$.

Answer (score 3):

My comment above is already a hint. And here the definition along with a further hint are listed.
**Definition:**
A subset $I$ of a ring $R$ is called an ideal if it satisfies the following two conditions:
**I.** $$\forall a, b\in I, a-b\in I.$$
**II.** $$\forall a\in I, r\in R, ra\in I.$$

Notice that the first implies that $I$ is a subgroup under the addition in $R.$
**Hint:**
If an element $a$ belongs to every element $I_\lambda$ of a family $\{I_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of ideals, then also $a\in \bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda} I_\lambda.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does 'a subset $I$ of a ring $R$ is a subgroup under the addition in $R$' guarantee the first condition of $H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$ be an ideal of $R$?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, yes: for a subset to be a subgroup, it needs indeed to satisfy the first condition here, in effect.

Comment: Thank you. $H_i$ is an ideal means it is a subring of $R$. It is not a subgroup of $R$ for multiplication. Now, how to guarantee that $H_1∩H_2∩...∩H_n$ fulfill the second condition?